# How can I check if a vector is pointing to null vector in a 2d-vector in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

So, I have the following case:

I declared a vector of vector of integers as `vector < vector<int> > edges`. Basically, I am trying to implement a graph using the above where graph is defined as follows:

```
class graph
{
    public:
    int vertices;
    vector < vector<int> > edges;
};
```

Now, during the insertion of an edge, I take input as the starting vertex and ending vertex. Now, I want to do something like this:

```
void insert(int a, int b, graph *mygraph) // a is starting vertex and b is ending vertex
{ 
    auto it = mygraph->edges.begin();
    //int v = 1;
    vector<int> foo;
    foo.push_back(b);
    if (mygraph->edges[a].size() != 0) // Question here?
        mygraph->edges[a].push_back(b);
    else
        mygraph->edges.push_back(foo);

    return;
}
```

Now, in the line marked with `Question here`, basically, I want to check if the vector for that particular entry exists or not? `size` is actually wrong because I am trying to call size operation on a vector which doesn't exists. In other words, I want to check, if there is a vector which exists at a particular location in vector of vectors. How can I do it? Something like, `mygraph->edges[a] != NULL`?

Comment: It will exist if and only if `a < mygraph->edges.size()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check that *a* does not exceed size of the vector. If it does, then resize the outer vector.

```
void insert(int a, int b, graph &mygraph) { // a is starting vertex and b is ending vertex
    if (a >= mygraph.edges.size())
        mygraph.edges.resize(a+1);
    mygraph.edges[a].push_back(b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can approach your problem in two different ways:

1. Initialize `edges` to the number of vertices, and don't allow other vertices to be inserted after that. Why is that?

   ```
   std::vector< std::vector<int> > v = { {1}, {2} };
   // now you need to add an edge between vertex 4 and vertex 5
   std::vector<int> edges3;
   v.push_back(edges3); // v = { {1}, {2}, {} }
   std::vector<int> edges4 = {5};
   v.push_back(edges4); // v = { {1}, {2}, {}, {5} }
   ```

   If you don't want to do it like that, you'd have to do something like this first:

   ```
   std::vector< std::vector<int> > v;
   for (int i = 0; i < maxVertices; i++)
   {
       std::vector<int> w;
       v.push_back(w);
   }
   // now you need to add an edge between vertex 4 and vertex 5
   v[4].push_back(5);
   ```
2. Change the structure used for `edges`, probably to something better suited for sparse matrices (which looks like your case here, since probably not every vertex is connected to every other vertex). Try:

   ```
   std::map< int, std::vector<int> > edges;
   ```

   That way you can match a single vertex with a list of other vertices without the need to initialize `edges` to the maximum possible number of vertices.

   ```
   std::vector<int> vertices = {5};
   edges[4] = vertices;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Edges is a vector of vectors. Vectors are stored contiguously in memory. You insert elements into a vector from the end. If the size of vector is 10, all 10 members are contiguous and their indexes are going to range from 0-9. If you delete a middle vector, say 5th, all vectors from index 6-9 get shifted up by 1.

The point of saying all this is that you can't have a situation where edges would have an index that doesn't hold a vector. To answer your question, a vector for index a would exist if

> a < mygraph->edges.size ();